# In selenium, does a windows needs to be expanded to max in order to locate the object?

Tags: selenium

In selenium, does a browser window needs to be max out before an object can be located? If a browser window is not expanded all the way, does that mean object CAN NOT be located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part, no -- an object can be located off screen. There are certain exceptions to this. Items that are hidden by things like `display:none` or if items are loaded as the user scrolls. Things like that -- dynamic -- you'll need to scroll the browser to trigger the loading.